# How can I upload several pictures at once on Foodspotting?

Tags: foodspotting

Is there any way to upload several pictures at once on Foodspotting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently don't have an easy way to do this... we used to allow bulk uploading via email and have always wanted to make a Mac widget where you can drop multiple photos and upload them. But unfortunately haven't had the bandwidth to do it. But we'll keep it in mind as we prioritize features for 2014!

Alexa (Foodspotting Cofounder)